# Conveying additional program state info through custom exception handling

Tags: c#, exception

In short, I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
public class AssetParseException : Exception
{
    public AssetParseException()
    {

    }

    public AssetParseException( string message/*, int assetID*/ ): base(message)
    {

    }
}
```

Ideally this would give me this functionality:

```
catch (AssetParseException exception)
{
    int idThatCausedIssue = exception.assetID;
}
```

The extra information I would like is the integer parameter. I would like to catch AssetParseExceptions at a higher level and know which asset threw the exception. Is this possible? Do I need to just shove all this information into the message and then parse it out at a higher level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Add:

`public int AssetID {get; private set;}`

to your `AssetParseException` class and set it when you create a new exception using

```
AssetParseException(string message, int assetID):base(message)
{
   AssetID = assetID;
}
```

We do it all the time.  It's always nice to know additional information about an exception, and why not put it in since you've gone to the trouble to throw a specific type of one.

Comment: no worries.  It's the small mistakes at times that drives us batty :)

Answer (score 3):

You most definitely can do that.

Are you confused about how to do it? Or just wondering if it is good practice? In my opinion, it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Custom exceptions are generally fine, especially in this case where you're providing more specific information about the error. Some things to keep in mind:

- If code that throws this exception will be referenced by other projects, make sure to expose the class as public so it can be used in catch statements elsewhere.
- You should probably document the fact that methods may throw this custom exception; you can use xml-doc comments with the 'exception' tags to specify the types of exceptions this method may throw out.
- Exceptions are often, but not always, typed to be used for a particular type of error. If parsing can fail in different ways that you want to be able to handle individually, consider further subclassing such as AssetParseNullValueException, AssetParseEncodingException, etc instead of incorporating this information as more fields or message data.
- Further to the previous point, messages on exceptions are generally what's shown to the user. Creating messages designed primarily to be parsed back out by code is not their purpose.